# How to get the load balancer address from a Docker container?

Tags: docker, load-balancing

I have a web app running on a Docker container behind a load balancer, and in one of the responses I'm returning a callback URL. The problem is that the callback URL resolves to the Docker container name instead of the load balancer address (which is public).

How can I get the load balancer address to construct the callback URL?

Comment: Web apps are probably not aware of any load balancers in front of them. You'll probably need a configuration setting in your web app that would store the load balancer address, and use this settings to build the callback URL.

Comment: @Helen, hardcoding addresses is my last resort.